# Exceeding the size of vendor

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

Hi I couldn't change size or divide vendor in nuxt what makes server doesn't want to load and after few seconds quit.

The issue is I was about introducing nuxt auth when the server unluckily returned this. terminal response is below.

Earlier everything works good but unexpectedly doesn't want to load and after few seconds server quits every time I tried to run this app.

In addition even after removing part of code before server runs good, this error still occurs or after creating new project vendor is still to big but everything works until exceeding size a bit by adding some file.

I found out this issue is connected to the size of the vendor and
tried to modify build in nuxt.config.js to change size of chunks or even try to divide it to smaller part but nothing works.

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

In npm run generate

```
13:54:04 ✔ Nuxt files generated

✔ Client
  Compiled successfully in 18.61s

✔ Server
  Compiled successfully in 11.82s


13:54:17  WARN  Unable to update lock within the stale threshold

  at options.fs.stat (node_modules/proper-lockfile/lib/lockfile.js:136:25)
  at node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:285:20
  at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:5)


Hash: a63f30e1da8b54b4e1e5
Version: webpack 4.31.0
Time: 18616ms
Built at: 2019-05-12 13:54:26
                         Asset       Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
../server/client.manifest.json   18.5 KiB          [emitted]         
       19efd8abbee3a8a33be4.js   1.66 KiB       4  [emitted]         pages/register
       35ca09b69194d90b94ba.js  284 bytes       2  [emitted]         pages/index
       3e8ab344ce99545b414a.js    189 KiB       1  [emitted]         commons.app
       40bd82d4e1d1a04a75a9.js   2.27 KiB       5  [emitted]         runtime
                      LICENSES   2.26 KiB          [emitted]         
       be138e70225ef677bf11.js   49.2 KiB       0  [emitted]         app
       ea98f7e0cb05705cdd19.js   2.09 KiB       3  [emitted]         pages/login
       ebfb93d5cff67de3634c.js    413 KiB       6  [emitted]  [big]  vendors.app
 + 2 hidden assets
Entrypoint app = 40bd82d4e1d1a04a75a9.js 3e8ab344ce99545b414a.js ebfb93d5cff67de3634c.js be138e70225ef677bf11.js

WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets: 
  ebfb93d5cff67de3634c.js (413 KiB)

Hash: 2686db6f213979a0c61c
Version: webpack 4.31.0
Time: 11817ms
Built at: 2019-05-12 13:54:38
                  Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
451e987fc41d64bb12d2.js   1.35 KiB       2  [emitted]  pages/login
6365a6c7ab9c235b4be2.js  330 bytes       1  [emitted]  pages/index
b65301e6570f75dc06a3.js   1.61 KiB       3  [emitted]  pages/register
              server.js    398 KiB       0  [emitted]  app
   server.manifest.json  483 bytes          [emitted]  
 + 4 hidden assets
Entrypoint app = server.js server.js.map
13:54:38 ℹ Generating pages
13:54:40 ✔ Generated /login
13:54:40 ✔ Generated /register
13:54:40 ✔ Generated /
```

and after npm run dev

```
13:48:02 ℹ Preparing project for development
13:48:02 ℹ Initial build may take a while
13:48:02 ✔ Builder initialized
13:48:02 ✔ Nuxt files generated

✔ Client
  Compiled successfully in 7.71s

✔ Server
  Compiled successfully in 5.85s

13:48:16 ℹ Waiting for file changes
13:48:16 ℹ Memory usage: 151 MB (RSS: 260 MB)

<--- Last few GCs --->

[4505:0x10264a000]    79635 ms: Mark-sweep 1264.9 (1425.4) -> 1264.0 (1425.9) MB, 1629.7 / 0.2 ms  (average mu = 0.216, current mu = 0.135) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[4505:0x10264a000]    81812 ms: Mark-sweep 1265.2 (1425.9) -> 1264.8 (1427.4) MB, 1912.8 / 0.3 ms  (average mu = 0.168, current mu = 0.121) deserialize GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x41f436e5261]
Security context: 0x30d36aa9e6e9 <JSObject>
    1: createContext(aka createContext) [0x30d31809fa31] [vm.js:~240] [pc=0x41f435541c1](this=0x30d36df826f1 <undefined>,/* anonymous */=0x30d33fda7019 <Object map = 0x30d3de4c0fd1>,/* anonymous */=0x30d33fda7121 <Object map = 0x30d36ac02571>)
    2: runInNewContext [0x30d3180823e9] [vm.js:135] [bytecode=0x30d3452e00c9 offset=15](this=0x30d35c4822a1 <Contexti...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0x10003c597 node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]
 2: 0x10003c7a1 node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 3: 0x1001ad575 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 4: 0x100579242 v8::internal::Heap::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 5: 0x10057bd15 v8::internal::Heap::CheckIneffectiveMarkCompact(unsigned long, double) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 6: 0x100577bbf v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 7: 0x100575d94 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 8: 0x100579172 v8::internal::Heap::ReserveSpace(std::__1::vector<v8::internal::Heap::Chunk, std::__1::allocator<v8::internal::Heap::Chunk> >*, std::__1::vector<unsigned long, std::__1::allocator<unsigned long> >*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 9: 0x100855687 v8::internal::DefaultDeserializerAllocator::ReserveSpace() [/usr/local/bin/node]
10: 0x10085e035 v8::internal::PartialDeserializer::Deserialize(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSGlobalProxy>, v8::DeserializeInternalFieldsCallback) [/usr/local/bin/node]
11: 0x10085dfd4 v8::internal::PartialDeserializer::DeserializeContext(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::SnapshotData const*, bool, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSGlobalProxy>, v8::DeserializeInternalFieldsCallback) [/usr/local/bin/node]
12: 0x100867455 v8::internal::Snapshot::NewContextFromSnapshot(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSGlobalProxy>, unsigned long, v8::DeserializeInternalFieldsCallback) [/usr/local/bin/node]
13: 0x100233c36 v8::internal::Genesis::Genesis(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::MaybeHandle<v8::internal::JSGlobalProxy>, v8::Local<v8::ObjectTemplate>, unsigned long, v8::DeserializeInternalFieldsCallback, v8::internal::GlobalContextType) [/usr/local/bin/node]
14: 0x100217f91 v8::internal::Bootstrapper::CreateEnvironment(v8::internal::MaybeHandle<v8::internal::JSGlobalProxy>, v8::Local<v8::ObjectTemplate>, v8::ExtensionConfiguration*, unsigned long, v8::DeserializeInternalFieldsCallback, v8::internal::GlobalContextType) [/usr/local/bin/node]
15: 0x1001cd8c7 v8::NewContext(v8::Isolate*, v8::ExtensionConfiguration*, v8::MaybeLocal<v8::ObjectTemplate>, v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value>, unsigned long, v8::DeserializeInternalFieldsCallback) [/usr/local/bin/node]
16: 0x1001af159 v8::Context::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::ExtensionConfiguration*, v8::MaybeLocal<v8::ObjectTemplate>, v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value>, v8::DeserializeInternalFieldsCallback) [/usr/local/bin/node]
17: 0x1000422d1 node::NewContext(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::ObjectTemplate>) [/usr/local/bin/node]
18: 0x10006345b node::contextify::ContextifyContext::CreateV8Context(node::Environment*, v8::Local<v8::Object>, node::contextify::ContextOptions const&) [/usr/local/bin/node]
19: 0x10006324f node::contextify::ContextifyContext::ContextifyContext(node::Environment*, v8::Local<v8::Object>, node::contextify::ContextOptions const&) [/usr/local/bin/node]
20: 0x100064ab1 node::contextify::ContextifyContext::MakeContext(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) [/usr/local/bin/node]
21: 0x41f436e5261 
22: 0x41f435541c1 
23: 0x41f42d918d5 
Abort trap: 6
```

and also terminal response after making new nuxt project and run npm run generate

```
✔ Client
  Compiled successfully in 19.49s

✔ Server
  Compiled successfully in 12.06s


14:31:30  ERROR  (node:5036) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on .hooks instead


14:31:34  WARN  Unable to update lock within the stale threshold

  at options.fs.stat (node_modules/proper-lockfile/lib/lockfile.js:136:25)
  at node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:285:20
  at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:5)


Hash: 523464a4f215ecad138a
Version: webpack 4.31.0
Time: 19497ms
Built at: 2019-05-12 14:31:49
                         Asset       Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
../server/client.manifest.json   17.2 KiB          [emitted]         
       5359710684b4ec80d12c.js   2.22 KiB       3  [emitted]         runtime
       5ad858d838bf3e368436.js   3.65 KiB       2  [emitted]         pages/index
       6773aee58a76de65a958.js    164 KiB       1  [emitted]         commons.app
       6953a06a30bda4b69151.js    413 KiB       4  [emitted]  [big]  vendors.app
       7ec00afb1f7acea69260.js   34.1 KiB       0  [emitted]         app
                      LICENSES    1.8 KiB          [emitted]         
icons/icon_120.9mld2VBMsQ$.png   3.05 KiB          [emitted]         
icons/icon_144.9mld2VBMsQ$.png   3.78 KiB          [emitted]         
icons/icon_152.9mld2VBMsQ$.png   3.96 KiB          [emitted]         
icons/icon_192.9mld2VBMsQ$.png   5.01 KiB          [emitted]         
icons/icon_384.9mld2VBMsQ$.png     11 KiB          [emitted]         
icons/icon_512.9mld2VBMsQ$.png   13.9 KiB          [emitted]         
 icons/icon_64.9mld2VBMsQ$.png   1.61 KiB          [emitted]         
        manifest.89571180.json  831 bytes          [emitted]         
 + 2 hidden assets
Entrypoint app = 5359710684b4ec80d12c.js 6773aee58a76de65a958.js 6953a06a30bda4b69151.js 7ec00afb1f7acea69260.js

WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets: 
  6953a06a30bda4b69151.js (413 KiB)

Hash: 86e05930b1fece3cf75c
Version: webpack 4.31.0
Time: 12068ms
Built at: 2019-05-12 14:32:01
                  Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
7d1bee16c2e1af97f877.js   3.71 KiB       1  [emitted]  pages/index
              server.js    386 KiB       0  [emitted]  app
   server.manifest.json  243 bytes          [emitted]  
 + 2 hidden assets
Entrypoint app = server.js server.js.map
14:32:01 ℹ Generating pages
14:32:02 ✔ Generated /
```

Comment: nuxt version ? And it seems that its some code that cause out of memory error

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/auth": "^4.5.3",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.4.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.11",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "nuxt": "^2.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9"
  }

Comment: that dont tell exact nuxt version, it could be anything between 2.4.0 and 2.6.3. Try to update to 2.6.3. If your issue isnt gone there no way to tell what wrong without a reproduction repository

Comment: I'm new to nuxt that's why I'm asking about it how exactly can I check my nuxt version or upgrade it? thanks for help.

Comment: delete your lock file file and node modules and reinstall. That way u will get latest version

Comment: ok thanks I'll do this and write if problem still exists

Comment: then u need to create a reproduction repository where u problem exist

Comment: Ok after delete node modules by using this cd /usr/local/lib and after sudo rm -rf node* and download not LTS version, but the latest one of node modules and reinstall npm by using this commend sudo npm install -g @vue/cli I create nuxt project by using npx create-nuxt-app <app name> integrated server framework: none, support: Progressive Web App, UI Framework: Bootstrap, Testing Framework: none, Nuxt Mode: Universal, Axios module: none, and run npx run generate by console returns the same response that vendor is too big Do you need any additional information ?

Comment: and I also discovered that in every file made by npx create-nuxt-app there is a file dist, is it normal or problem could be here?

Comment: and also even if I try to delete dist folder and run npm run generate dist folder is creating once again.

Comment: first -> that warning is just a warning, it wont crash an app or anything like this . second - dist is a folder that will be created when u do generate.

Comment: ok, thanks for explanation so whta would you recommend?

Comment: recommend for what? For your memory crash e.g. FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap - u need to provide actual repository where it happnes. For warning - nothing, use other than bootstrap lib if it critical for you

Answer (score 0):

You could try this config in nuxt.config.js to enforce a size on the build chunks

```
 /*
  ** Build configuration
  */
  build: {
    /*
    ** You can extend webpack config here
    */
    extend (config, ctx) {
      if (ctx && ctx.isClient) {
        config.optimization.splitChunks.maxSize = 64000
      }
    }
  }
```